# Most Common Second Query, Given the First - SQL Grouping

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate

I have a table like this:

```
Item Selected    Session ID      Created
    A             1         2017-11-25T02:22:23
    B             1         2017-11-25T02:22:24
    B             1         2017-11-25T02:22:25
    C             1         2017-11-25T02:22:17
    D             1         2017-11-25T02:22:27
    A             2         2017-11-25T02:22:28
    C             2         2017-11-25T02:22:30
    D             2         2017-11-25T02:22:06
```

I want to know, given Item A, which is the most likely next 3-5 Items selected during the same session ID, across all sessions.

In other words, after Users select Item A, what items do they most often select next?

A preferred output for an Item A query would be something like:

```
2nd Item Selected       Percent of time selected
     B                      33%
     C                      33%
     D                      33%
```

Is this possible in SQL?

EDIT: This is the current solution, but it isn't working in BigQuery. I'm posting my exact code, with the table_name changed:

```
select `tag_touched`, count(*) / numsessions as ratio
from (select s.`session_id`, `tag_touched`, max(created) as 
maxcreated, a.maxcreated_a, ss.numsessions
      from [TABLENAME] s join
           (select s.`session_id`, max(s.Created) as maxcreated_a
            from [TABLENAME] s
            where `tag_touched` = 'A'
            group by s.`session_id`,
       ) a
       on s.`session_id` = a.`session_id` cross join
       (select count(distinct `session_id`) as numsessions
        from [TABLENAME]
        where `tag_touched` = 'A'
       ) ss
  group by s.`session_id`, s.`tag_touched`, a.maxcreated_a, ss.numsessions
  having max(created) > maxcreated_a
 ) s
group by `tag_touched`;
```

But I'm returning the error:

```
Error: Expression '`tag_touched`' is not present in the GROUP BY list
```

Advice?

Comment: Where do your percentages come from?  They seem to have nothing to do with the data you have provided.

Comment: Sorry I corrected them to make sense with the data provided

Comment: Are you looking at any item selected following A or only items selected *immediately after* A.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of which items are selected after a given item in the same session using aggregation.  I think this might be sufficient for what you want to do:

```
select item, count(*) / numsessions as ratio
from (select s.sessionId, s.item, max(s.created) as maxcreated, a.maxcreated_a, ss.numsessions
      from sessions s join
           (select sessionId, max(created) as maxcreated_a
            from sessions s
            where item = 'A'
            group by sessionId
           ) a
           on s.sessionId = a.sessionId cross join
           (select count(distinct sessionId) as numsessions
            from sessions
            where item = 'A'
           ) ss
      group by s.sessionId, s.item, a.maxcreated_a, ss.numsessions
      having max(created) > maxcreated_a -- appeared after the last "A"
     ) s
group by item;
```

Comment: I'm trying to test this but running into errors. What is the "s" and "a" after the parentheses? ( like "from sessions s" , or "from sessions where item = 'A' ) ss"

Comment: @AshleyO Those are aliases for the subqueries. Most (all?) platforms require you to give them a name even if you don't actually refer to it later.

Comment: @shawnt00 thank you for that, it works in SQL fiddle but on BigQuery it returns "ambiguous field reference sessionId". sessionId is definitely a column, but how would I fix that? Do i have to specify the table .sessionId?

Comment: @AshleyO I fixed the ambiguous reference in my query. Note the use of aliases in the subqueries. Yes, I think that was the `Session ID` but I went ahead and addressed all of them.

Comment: update: it passed that part but now is saying: 'Error: Expression 's.`sessionId`' is not present in the GROUP BY list'. Working on that

Comment: fixed that, but now it says "expression 'item' is not present in the GROUP BY list'. BigQuery is tough :(

Comment: Double-check the aliases and make sure it all matches up between the `group by` and the `select` list. Perhaps one is `s` while the other is `ss`. There are two places in there that could be causing it.

Comment: I've triple double checked and it appears to be exactly the same as yours? I added my exact code to the original post so you can see. I'm still fiddling to see if there is a fix though